# Triggering a method in the parent class of the class that had the control that sent a command to it's viewmodel

Tags: c#, events, xamarin

Background:
I am trying to get xamarin forms to implement the interface I want and the closest way I could find to do it is by having a page that uses a grid to call contentviews. and I am going to have to implement my own top toolbar, menu, and tabbar.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<ContentPage xmlns="http://xamarin.com/schemas/2014/forms"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2009/xaml"
             xmlns:prism="clr-namespace:Prism.Mvvm;assembly=Prism.Forms"
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:DNB_Prism_Map.Views"
             prism:ViewModelLocator.AutowireViewModel="True"
             x:Class="DNB_Prism_Map.Views.MergePage">
    <StackLayout>
        <Grid RowSpacing="0" ColumnSpacing="0" Margin="0" Padding="0">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="20" />
                <RowDefinition Height="40" />
                <RowDefinition Height="*" />
                <RowDefinition Height="47" />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                <ColumnDefinition Width="0"/>
            </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <BoxView BackgroundColor="#222222" Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <local:ToolbarView x:Name="Toolbar" Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Grid.ColumnSpan="2"/>
            <BoxView x:Name="MenuCell" BackgroundColor="Gainsboro" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Grid.RowSpan="2"/>
            <BoxView x:Name="TargetCell" BackgroundColor="Yellow" Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="1"/>
            <local:TabbarView x:Name="Tabbar" Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="1"/>

        </Grid>
        <AbsoluteLayout x:Name="Menu" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutBounds="0,0,-1,-1" AbsoluteLayout.LayoutFlags="PositionProportional" >
            <local:MainPageMaster />
        </AbsoluteLayout>
    </StackLayout>
</ContentPage>
```

Issue:
As you can see above I have Toolbar contentview that is loaded and on that toolbar is a button that is bound to an command in ToolbarViewModel this toggles a property of the ViewModel. Now the part I can't figure out is how to run a method on the contentPage when the state of that property changes.

The examples I find only connect back to the view or page that has the button and I want it to fire a method on the Page that loaded the view with the button.
All this binding, MVVM, events stuff is new to me and seems overly complex.

Comment: What method are you trying to run on the content page?

Comment: You don't normally "fire methods" on the page - you update state. The button would typically be hidden and IsVisible bound to a property on the view model. The command would update the property which would show the button.

Comment: And I have to say, I think you are making things too complex by implementing your own top toolbar, menu, and tabbar. Xamarin Forms gives you a lot of things out of the box and if you find yourself having to write a lot of your own stuff, it's worth stepping back and seeing if you can change the UI to meet Xamarin Forms requirements. I had a lot of screen designs from the UX department that were too difficult in XF and by suggesting a compromise managed the same functionality with simpler screens.

Comment: The navigation bar doesn't do what i want. I don't want page titles but the appname and logo in the center and the ability to swap out that space with a search entry. On top of this I cant get the navbar, masterdetail, and tabpage to work together. I can get it to look right for the base page but if I add a stacked page i loose something, either the tabs, or nav, or both. I asked how to do that in a previous question but got no satisfactory answer so I moved on to rolling my own by having one page and swapping contentviews around programmatically.